# EXCEL IF and AND nested

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I cannot get my IF and AND statements to work for the following criteria:

- Green if cell is between -0.02 and +0.02
- Amber if cell is between -0.02 and -0.05
- Amber if cell is between +0.02 and +0.05
- Red if cell is less than -0.05 or more than +0.05

It's the dual amber criteria that I think is throwing me off. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: is this for conditional formatting, or do you want a cell formula?

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
=IF(AND(A1>=-0.02,A1<=0.02),"Green",IF(AND(A1>=-0.05,A1<=-0.02),"Amber",IF(AND(A1>=0.02,A1<=0.05),"Amber",IF(OR(A1<-0.05,A1>0.05),"Red","Oops"))))
```

For future reference, it's best when you post a question to at least post what code you've tried, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.  However, in your original question, you do not indicate what you want returned if a value is **exactly equal** to the boundaries.  So you may have to alter the lookup array a bit if this does not return what you expect.

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{-9E+307,-0.05,-0.02,0.02,0.05},{"Red","Amber","Green","Amber","Red"})
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not too clear from the question, but I assumed you were trying to setup conditional formatting rules to color your cells. You could use a setup like this:

[image]

As noted by others, you have some overlap on the boundaries (for example, is 0.02 green or amber?). You can make it go either way depending on the order in which you define the formatting rules (the rules are applied in order shown).